# What formula would allow incrementing a number each time a certain name appears in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I add a list of names to a spreadsheet and each time a specific name appears add the number 10 to cell.  For example, I would put a name like Jones in A1 then Jones in A5. And in D5 it would have the number 20. If I then add Jones in B2 then D5 would say 30. Add 10 each time Jones appears.

What   formula  would I use?

Comment: Please supply sample data and your expected results. It is difficult to understand what you are asking, however I think a combination of IF() and ISTEXT() might work.

Comment: Could you just tell us from where you are getting names to add and on what ground you are suppose to put 10 in adjacent cell, for every name or to specific names ?

Comment: I would put a name like Jones in A1 then Jones in A5. And in D5 it would have the number 20. If I then add Jones in B2  then D5 would say 30. Add 10 each time jones appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COUNTIF` function to count the number of times a value appears in a range.

If you simply want to count the number of times "Jones" appears in a given range and multiply that by 10, you can use the formula:

```
=COUNTIF("A1:C99","Jones")*10
```

If your names are in column A starting at row 1, and you want the numbers in column B to count the number of times the name in column A is found, enter the following formula in cell B1:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)*10
```

Now copy that cell and paste it in the rest of column B. when you paste the formula, `A$1` will remain the same, but `A1` will be changed to include the row number where the formula is pasted. For example, the formula in cell B5 will be:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A5,A5)*10
```

The formula will count the number of times the name in column A occurs in all of column A from row 1 through the current row, then multiply that by 10.

[image]